# Implement the serialization and deserialization functions of a doubly linked list defined as follows:

Tags: java, serialization, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Good day for all.
One company give me an interesting task without a binding to a particular language. I have found some implementation on C++ and C#, but I am a java prog and not able to completely understand how to make it with java.

**Task:**

You can use any commonly used language to complete the task.
The test should be performed without the use of libraries / standard serialization tools. Implement the serialization and deserialization functions of a doubly linked list defined as follows:

```
class ListNode
{
    public ListNode Prev;
    public ListNode Next;
    public ListNode Rand; //random element
    public string Data;
}


class ListRand
{
    public ListNode Head;
    public ListNode Tail;
    public int Count;

    public void Serialize(FileStream s)
    {
    }

    public void Deserialize(FileStream s)
    {
    }
}
```

I understand how doubly linked list works. I have found standard linked list realization(it doesn't have variable **Count**, Node doesn't have variable **Rand**). What should I do with this variables?

I have found the simmilar theme on SO and with it my code now looks like:

```
public class ListRand implements Serializable {

    private ListNode Head;
    private ListNode Tail;
    private int Count;

public void Serialize(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {

    for (ListNode e = Head; e!=null; e = e.getNext()) {
        out.writeObject(e.getData());
    }
}

public void Deserialize(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    in.defaultReadObject();

}

}
```

Plz, give me some advices, i wanna resolve this task by my self, because I have never do the same tasks.

Comment: The question doesn't ask you to implement it. It asks you to serialize and deserialize it. And it tells you *The test should be performed without the use of libraries / standard serialization tools*. So you *may not* use Serializable and ObjectOutputStream. Because these are precisely the standard serialization tools that you may not use. You need to write everything the data structure contains to a stream of bytes, and be able to recreate it from that stream of bytes. All by yourself.

Comment: The main complexity being to avoid storing the same node an infinity of times, due to the cycles in the data structure.

Comment: @JBNizet Could you give me a couple of lines java code for this? I am not able to find solution how to write information about links of random nodes.